# Java Subarray with specific size from array

Tags: java, arrays

If I have array like [1,2,3,4] and k = 3 then output should be [1,2,3][2,3,4] which is in  this order. The idea is to get subarray with k elements and then the next to start from the next element and also to have k elements
I can't think of a way to do it more generic for any value of k.

```
    final int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    final int max = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < max; k = k + 2) {
                System.out.println(i + "" + j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). It seems like your problem is that you've not yet understood how for loops work; probably you need to go and read some more and do a lot of experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract parts of an array by calling Arrays.copyOfRange() method:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int k = 3;
   
int numberOfResults = arr.length - k + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResults; i++) {
    int[] result = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,i,i+k);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```